# use progressbar to indicate in the course of downloading image

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

The following is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" /> 

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>           
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm trying to downlaod an image given the url link and then show the image on the `ImageView`. Before the image is ready, the `ProgressBar` shows on the `ImageView`. Till so far, my code can download the image and show it on the `ImageView`. There is an obvious delay before the image shows up since downloading takes time. Can anyone give me some suggestions? I'm new to android and this is not a homework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AsyncTask... Here is a good tutorial on it:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/